# Netflix RxJava vs Spring Reactor

Tags: reactor

I am  evaluating reactor library for using it in our project. I googled a lot but couldn't find the difference(pros /cons) between Netflix's RxJava and Spring's Reactor API. can someone please help me in deciding or provide some pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: Was looking for some info on this and found the following article that could be useful: http://akarnokd.blogspot.com/2015/10/comparison-of-reactive-streams.html

Comment: Great comparison of RxJava and Reactor available at http://alexsderkach.io/comparing-java-8-rxjava-reactor/ Compares many different aspects and also considers the simpler, more specialized Java8 Stream, CompletableFuture and Optional

Comment: Tweet from David Karnok, *project lead of RxJava & engine contributor to Reactor 3*: **Use Reactor 3 if you are allowed to use Java 8+, use RxJava 2 if you are stuck on Java 6+ or need your functions to throw checked exceptions** https://twitter.com/akarnokd/status/774590596740685824

Comment: This link may be useful https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2019/02/rxjava-vs-reactor.html

Answer (score 24):

There isn't a single document that lists the pros and cons of RxJava versus Reactor. We don't see it being a mutually exclusive relationship. If you need the holistic Reactive approach of RxJava Observables, then use that and maybe add Reactor as a Scheduler implementation to get the high speed dispatching. If you're more interested in the functional, low-latency, lambda pipeline approach, then maybe choose Reactor as the foundation with the option to add Observables as the payload of objects passing through the Stream.

Each has its strengths and weaknesses and you just have decide, based on your understanding of what those are, what the final balance is. No one can tell you that and any attempt to do so would be disingenuous to say the least.